# WFFM 8.2 rev. 160801 : error when adding form programatically

Tags: wffm

I'm working on a migration project from 6.5 to 8.2. 
I've installed a clean WFFM 8.2 and I'm trying to refactor the existing code.

It adds the WFFM form programatically as follows:

**ASCX**

```
  <div runat="server" class="grid_13" id="OpeningFormDiv">
  </div>
```

**ASCX.CS - original code**

```
  FormRender Form = new FormRender
        {
            FormID = GetParameter("FormID"),                
            ReadQueryString = GetParameter("ReadQueryString"),
            FormTemplate = "/sitecore modules/web/Web Forms for Marketers/Control/SitecoreSimpleFormAscx.ascx"
        };
  OpeningFormDiv.Controls.Add(Form);
```

**ASCX.CS - "new" code**

```
  SitecoreSimpleForm form = new SitecoreSimpleForm(Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(GetParameter("FormID")));
  var test = new FormRender(form);
   OpeningFormDiv.Controls.Add(test);
```

the new code has the same effect (and basically does the same thing).
both throw and exception stating that the innerItem is empty:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: innerItem

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.
Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: innerItem
```

All the code samples I've found online are using this method, so I think I'm on the right track here. Does anyone have an idea what might be wrong?
When debugging the FormId and Querystring parameters are retrieved correctly and the SitecoreSimpleForm is created as normal. The error occurs when the form is added to the controls of the div.

Comment: Can you see if the `Context.Database` is correct and all required items have been published?

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. I'm republishing the templates and layouts now...

Comment: Has the publishing fix the issue?

Comment: now I'm getting unrecognized GUId format. But I'm also seeing a broken links gutter, so It's probably some item linked in the form. At least the code  is correct. thanks!

Comment: Hi Rueben. This question is a bit on a spin. I saw your updated question edit, but you should really post a new question under a separate headline. It is not related to "Adding a WFFM form programatically".

Comment: @MarkCassidy will do...

Answer (score 1):

The reason why `innerItem` may be `null` is because it is not found on the target database.

Try to perform a republish and see if the issue is fixed.

Comment: Just to note: **Smart** publish may be faster in this case

Comment: @AndreyBobrov, yes or even incremental publish

Comment: This was only part of the answer. the real issue was the tracking field which causes the unrecognized GUID format error.